# Transaction in Azure Powershell command

Tags: powershell, azure, transactions

Can we write Azure Powershell command in a transaction like

Begin Transaction

Create Azure storage Acoount

Create Azure VM

Rollback/Commit Transaction

I tried [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/09/powershell-transactions-quickstart.aspx?Redirected=true)  but not clear we can use or not.

Any one with more detail about transaction with powershell command?

Comment: I did not found any way to associate transaction with Azure commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell cmdlets are built atop the Azure management [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). The API operations themselves are independent of other operations (there could be exceptions, but this is generally the case). So even with PowerShell transactions, the Azure cmdlets won't offer transactional operations against Azure.

Comment: Correct - though in theory someone could script a system that cleaned up after itself in failure scenarios at least.

Comment: Yup - you could do that. And it could probably be done pretty decently, at least in the *create* direction. In the *delete* case, some things (e.g. Storage/SQL DB deletions) can't be undone...